# Facebook JS SDK, FB.api handle other events like start, complete?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using the FB js sdk. I am a jquery and fb sdk beginner.

I am wondering how to handle other events when making .api or query . wait calls?

like.. show a throbber/loading gif at the start of a .wait call and hide it on complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm well, most Facebook Javascript calls have a callback functions so one way I could think of doing this would be:

```
$("#show-friends-albums").click(function() {
    $("#ajax-loader").show(); // Show the loader before the FB JS Call
    FB.api(
        {
            method: 'fql.query',
            query: 'SELECT aid,owner,name FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) LIMIT 25'
        },
        function(resp) {
            $("#ajax-loader").hide(); // We got a response, Hide and process the data
            $.each(resp, function(k,v) {
                console.log(v.name)
            })
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: does formatting the FB.api call like that work? i haven't tried it yet.. sorry. But if this works then this is exactly what i'm looking for. thanks!

Comment: @rodrick: Yes this is a working example, I've just added the `ajax-loader` bit, you can find more about the `FB.API` [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.api/). if you find the answer useful, please consider up-voting it!